# How to abbreviate first author names in the references when using the `multibib` package?

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

The `bibtex` and `biblatex` packages have options for abbreviating author names in the literature.

I am writing a document that requires separating references into categories. For this purpose I am using the `multibib` package and I cannot find any abbreviation option for author names in the [multibib documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf).

**Edit from koleygr:**

**MWE???:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{general1,
author    = "Myself,Me",
title     = "Some book",
year = "2000"
}


@book{Lastname1989,
title = {A Book},
author = {Lastname,Name},
year = {1989},
}

@book{Else1990,
title = {A Book},
author = { Else,Someone.},
year = {1990},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{B}{Extra References}
\begin{document}
Here is a normal citation \cite{general1} and an author citation :\citeauthor{general1}

Here is a citation for our second bibliography:
\citeB{Lastname1989} and another author for this bibliography is %\citeauthorB{Else1990}. %Somenting like this that would add the cited author name and the reference in second bibliography

\renewcommand{\refname}{General References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
    \bibliographystyleB{alpha}
\bibliographyB{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A MWE would help us to test some codes (ie use non `multibib`-specific commands)

Comment: The name format is not controlled by the `multibib` package. It is controlled by the bibliography style you use (the argument to `\bibliographystyle` or `\bibliographystyle<X>` in this case). Just pick a style that abbreviates names (such as `abbrv.bst` or `abbrvnat.bst` or ...). Which style do you use at the moment?

Comment: I added a MWE of what I suppose you want to get... Feel free to change it if I understood wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @moewe: this did the trick, if you formulate your comment as an answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multibib` only provides the framework that allows you to have multiple bibliographies in your document. It does not control the style of the bibliography output. That is still up to the `.bst` file you select with `\bibliographystyle<X>`.

So you can get initials if you switch to a style that prints only initials. One choice would be the standard `abbrv` style, but with `natbib` you may want to use `abbrvnat` and there are many more styles out there that print initials instead of full first names.